# .htaccess taking filesystem path

Tags: .htaccess

I'm trying to get a simple enough rule to work:

```
Input URL: http://example.com/css/styles.css/t=123456
Expected output: http://example.com/css/styles.css
```

The `t=123456` represents the file's modification time, which is automatically added on the server-side. Currently, it's a query string, but apparently that doesn't cache properly in some circumstances, so I want to encode it in the url instead.

The rule I tried is simple enough:

```
RewriteRule (.*)/t=[0-9]+ $1
```

But for some reason I kept getting 404 Not Found errors.

I added `[R=301]` to see where the rewrite was going, and for some reason I found this was the output URL:

```
http://example.com/home/evilzoro/public_html/css/styles.css
```

So, while it was correctly stripping out the parameter, it was adding the whole filesystem path in!

Bizarrely, other similar rules work just fine, such as this one:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !\.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [QSA]
```

So what am I doing wrong?

Comment: hmmm.... didn't you already ask this question? it mysteriously vanished.

Comment: I did, but I found out more information which made the old question somewhat-irrelevant.

Comment: at least we know your .stack Rewrite works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding a leading slash to the target of your rule. Apache has to guess whether you are referring to a file-path or a URI-path and sometimes it doesn't get it right.

```
RewriteRule (.*)/t=[0-9]+ /$1
```